# form return false wont work in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, forms, input, submit

This works in FF and Chrome, but I can't seem to stop the form from submitting in IE8.

JQuery is included in document ready function

```
$("#reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommate").click (function() {
    roommate = $("#roommate").val();
    $.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + roommate, function (response) {
    $("#roommateResults").html(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Relevant submit button in my form:

```
<input  type="image"
                        src="images/arrow.png"
                        class="reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommate"
                        id="reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommate">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try handling your form's `submit` event, rather than the submit button's `click` handler:

```
$("#yourFormId").submit (function() {
    roommate = $("#roommate").val();
    $.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + roommate, function (response) {
        $("#roommateResults").html(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, I will mark this as the answer in 6 mins when I am allowed.  But I'm still not getting action on the next step in internet explorer.  I think I'm going to have to post a different questions for that piece.  Thanks again! Brad

Comment: @radleybobins - you're very welcome.  I'm not quite sure what the solution is to your next step problem, so a new question would probably be your best bet :)